# Why isn't uWSGI respecting the "--http-keepalive" flag?

Tags: http, uwsgi, keep-alive

I installed uWSGI in a Docker container running `ubuntu:16.04` using the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y build-essential python-dev python-pip
pip install uwsgi
```

I then created a single static file:

```
cd /root
mkdir static
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1024 of=static/data
```

...and finally started uWSGI with the following command:

```
uwsgi \
    --buffer-size 32768 \
    --http-socket 0.0.0.0:80 \
    --processes 4 \
    --http-timeout 60 \
    --http-keepalive \
    --static-map2=/static=./
```

I was able to access the static file without any problems. However, despite passing the `--http-keepalive` option, issuing multiple requests with cURL resulted in the following output:

```
# curl -v 'http://myserver/static/data' -o /dev/null 'http://myserver/static/data' -o /dev/null
*   Trying 192.168.1.101...
...
> GET /static/data HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.101:8100
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 1024
< Last-Modified: Sat, 03 Dec 2016 22:06:49 GMT
< 
{ [1024 bytes data]
100  1024  100  1024    0     0   577k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1000k
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.101 left intact
* Found bundle for host 192.168.1.101: 0x563fbc855630 [can pipeline]
* Connection 0 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 0
...
```

Of particular interest is the line:

```
* Connection 0 seems to be dead!
```

This was confirmed with WireShark:

[image]

As you can see, there are two completely separate TCP connections. The first one is closed by uWSGI (packet #10 - the `[FIN, ACK]`).

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't uWSGI honor the `--http-keepalive` flag instead of immediately closing the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to get keepalive working by switching from `--http-socket` to simply `--http`. According to uWSGI docs:

> If your web server does not support the uwsgi protocol but is able to speak to upstream HTTP proxies, or if you are using a service like Webfaction or Heroku to host your application, you can use `http-socket`. If you plan to expose your app to the world with uWSGI only, use the `http` option instead, as the router/proxy/load-balancer will then be your shield.

In my particular case, it was also necessary to load the `http` plugin.

Comment: `http` plugin? required additional installation? can you show the working `uwsgi` command? just replacing the `http-socket` with `http`?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I faced with random 502 responses from aws ALB / ELB.
I provided configuration by .ini file like:

```
http-keepalive = true
```

but after hours of debugging, I saw a similar picture in Wireshark - after each response, the connection was closed by the server, so the keep-alive option was ignored

In [uWSGI#2018](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2018), the discussion points that it should be an integer (doc [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#http-keepalive)), but unfortunately can't find exact info on whether it represents seconds of socket lifetime, or it could be simple '1'. After this change - the random 502 disappeared and uwsgi started work in expected mode.

Hope it could be also helpful for somebody.

Comment: You are totally correct -- we had to change the value of --http-keepalive from true to 1 and our 502 problem went away.   We were able to show this with load testing the application before and after the change.